# Highcharts - Hide series "points" (labels) on both x- and y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I remove the series points/labels from both the x and y axis?

Below is my chart (with image on my code)

[image]

I want to remove the:
`0k, 20k, 40k, 60k` and the `0, 2.5, 5, 7.5` etc. points.

Code:

```
$(function () {
                $('#fullwidth').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'area',
                        backgroundColor: null
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    legend: {
                            enabled: false,
                     },
                    credits: {
                          enabled: false
                      },
                    xAxis: {

                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name} clicks <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false,
                                symbol: 'circle',
                                radius: 2,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{

                        name: 'Direct Referral',
                        color: '#40A8FF',
                        data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                            1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                            27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                            26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                            24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                            22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                            10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Rented Referral',
                        color: '#62C875',   
                        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null , null , null ,null,
                        5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                        4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                        15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                        33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                        35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                        21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
                    }]
                });
            });
```

I've been searching HighCharts docs, but I can't fint anything.
Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the property `labels` of both axis to `false`

```
xAxis: {
        labels:{enabled: false}
       },
yAxis: {
         labels:{enabled: false}
         gridLineWidth: 0,
         minorGridLineWidth: 0,
         title: {
          text: ''
         }
       },
```

Here you have a fiddle of the result: http://jsfiddle.net/3Xhra/